# Resilience4j - Can you use annotations like @Retry in a kotlin app without Spring Boot?

Tags: kotlin, annotations, circuit-breaker, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I'm currently implementing retries and circuitbreakers using Resilience4j. Most of the examples online are using Spring Boot online and noticed that @Retry and @CircuitBreaker annotations are being used. However, I was wondering if a similar approach could be used for a kotlin app without Spring MVC or SpringBoot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, annotations only work when you use a framework like Spring Boot, Micronaut or Ratpack